# Вопрос по прототипу

Tags: javascript, html

Есть небольшой код:

```
function cw(obj) {
  this.obj = document.getElementsByTagName(obj)[0];
  return document.getElementsByTagName(obj)[0];
}

cw.prototype.val = () => {
  return this.obj.innerText;
}
```

По-идее, такой код при

```
<button>ABCDE</button>
```

и

```
console.log(cw("button").val);
```

Должен возвращать "ABCDE", но, увы не работает.
Также, я для теста в консоли прописывал

```
cw("button")
this.obj.innerText
```

И эти строки возвращали нужные "ABCDE", а вот функция .val возвращает только
undefined.

В чём может быть ошибка? Пробовал и через try-catch - также ничего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function cw(obj) {
  this.obj = document.getElementsByTagName(obj)[0];
}

cw.prototype.val = function() {
  return this.obj.innerText;
}

console.log(new cw("button").val());
```

```html
<button>ABCDE</button>
```

> А как это реализовать без new?

```js
function cw(obj) {
  return {
    obj: document.getElementsByTagName(obj)[0],
    val: function() {
      return this.obj.innerText;
    }
  };
}

console.log(cw("button").val());
```

```html
<button>ABCDE</button>
```

Comment: А как это реализовать без new?

Comment: Но там всё ещё "new" :)

Comment: @TylerLowell Уже нет.

Comment: Всё, разобрался! Благодарю за ответ :)